# Problem with Flash ExternalInterface on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, flash, google-app-engine

I've been struggling with this for the past couple hours now and I really don't know what could be wrong. I'm simply trying to get Javascript to communicate text with Flash. I found this great example with this source

http://blog.circlecube.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/ActionscriptJavascriptCommunication.zip

I ran the html file locally and it works just fine sending and retrieving text from flash. Then I load that same exact sample into my dev google app server and I can't send the text from javascript to flash. Oddly enough though flash is able to send Javascript text. Can anybody see if they can get this running with GAE? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a call to the allowDomain function in your code.  With out that the security sandbox will not allow your flash application to communicate with flash and vice versa on the server.  Add a call to `System.security.allowDomain("mydomain.com", "mySecondDomain.com", "etc.com")` for every domain the flash app will be executed on.  Also the embed code also needs to specify access for JavaScript by including the parameter `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />`.

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't have to do with Google app engine per se, since the whole thing's running in the browser -- unless there's some sort of server dependency somewhere you haven't mentioned.  Assuming that's not the case...

If you're able to get Flash to call into JavaScript with ExternalInterface.call(), but not JavaScript to call back into Flash, then it's probably one or two things:  your EI callback & handler aren't wired up properly (in Flash), or your JavaScript doesn't have a handle on the SWF object in the browser.

You might try posting some code, but in the meantime, here's something I know works in both IE and FireFox.  First, the browser code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var swfReady = false;

    function callbacksInitialized()
    {
        swfReady = true;
    }

    function helloFlash()
    {
        if (swfReady)
        {   
            // Get a handle on the Flash object
            var swfObject = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1 ? window["HelloMac"] : document["HelloMac"] ;

            // Call back into the Flash file 
            swfObject.helloFlash(document.getElementById("txtMessage").value);
        }
    }

    function helloMac(message)
    {
        alert(message);
    }

</script>
</head>
<body scroll="no">
    <div align="center">

        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
                id="HelloMac" width="600" height="300"
                codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                <param name="movie" value="HelloMac.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <embed src="HelloMac.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                    width="600" height="300" name="HelloMac" align="middle"
                    play="true"
                    loop="false"
                    quality="high"
                    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                </embed>
        </object>

        <br /><br />
        <input type="text" id="txtMessage" value="Hello, Flash!" /><br />
        <input id="btnSend" type="button" value="Send to Flash" onclick="helloFlash();" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And now, the Flash code (in my case, it's Flex, so hopefully it's clear):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" initialize="init()" height="300" width="600">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

            private function init():void
            {
                addCallbacks(); 
            }

            private function addCallbacks():void
            {
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("helloFlash", this_helloFlash);
                ExternalInterface.call("callbacksInitialized");
            }

            // Display a message from the host
            private function this_helloFlash(message:String):void
            {
                Alert.show(message);
            }

            // Send a string to the host
            private function helloMac():void
            {
                if (ExternalInterface.available)
                {
                    ExternalInterface.call("helloMac", txtMessage.text);
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:VBox horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <mx:TextInput id="txtMessage" text="Hello, Mac!" />
        <mx:Button id="btnSend" label="Send to Host" click="helloMac()" />
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

The example demonstrates Flash calling into JavaScript with some text, and JavaScript calling back into Flash in the same way.  Some points to pay attention to:

- Make sure you **wait** to call into
  Flash until Flash has notified the
  browser it's ready to begin receiving
  calls (as indicated by my
  callbacksInitialized() method).
- Test to be sure you're using the
  appropriate browser-specific object
  reference (e.g., window["HelloMac"]
  vs. document["HelloMac"]).

Without knowing more, I'm guessing it's one of these two items, since that's been my experience.  Hope it helps!  I'll keep an eye on the post for follow-ups in case you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Yup the answer by Christian Nunciato is helpful. The issue is that your swf file is not available to javascript at the time your javascript calls the flash function. Christian's trick makes sure the swf file is loaded and started when your javascript needs it.