# Calling flex application from php files

Tags: php, apache-flex

HI all,i need help please..Does anyone have suceeded to call flex application from php-html files?Suppose i got html-php based web,i make a ogin form using html tags.When the user have suceeded login,the login form which was created by using flex will be shown...Please help..Thanks a lot guys...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by having the HTML login form reveal a Flex login form, but if what you're trying to do is establish communication between HTML/JavaScript (however rendered, PHP or otherwise) and Flex, then what you'll want to use is [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

I [recently posted a complete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472026/problem-with-flash-externalinterface-on-google-app-engine#472184) that illustrates how to set things up on both ends (HTML/JavaScript and Flex), and how to get them to talk to one another.  You should be able to copy-paste both code snippets into a new Flex project to see a working example, and tweak as needed from there.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Flex:

```
...
// provide an interface for javascript
if (ExternalInterface.available) 
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("login", jsLogin);
...

private function jsLogin(name:String, password:String):void 
{
...
```

In Javascript

```
...
var name = $('#name').text();
var password = $('#password').text();
$('#swfobject').get(0).login(name, password);
```