# flash interaction with javascript internet explorer

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, interaction

I have a flash object interacting with a javascript function. The interaction works fine in every browser except in IE (all versions)
I have tried with swfobject and with classic embeding. AllowScriptAccess is set to "always". Is there any cause for this flaw ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using openURL(javascript:...)?

Comment: Can you please post the exact code you use to embed the Flash movie in your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ExternalInterface, the problem may be related to the way you're attempting to reference the object in JavaScript.  [Take a look at my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472026/problem-with-flash-externalinterface-on-google-app-engine#472184) -- it might not be exactly the same issue, but my answer provides an end-to-end example of ExternalInterface that's been tested on IE, too, so you might want to compare it to your own to see whether anything's missing or out of place.

If that doesn't help, though, try posting some code, so we can have a look at what's going on and maybe diagnose the problem more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the test from a file instead of testing it on a webserver it might be because security settings.